# htaccess does not work to force https whereas ssl is active

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a Wordpress website and to force all traffics over HTTPS, I 've used the code below in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Although, I can visit website on `https://` mode well, and there is not any other issue on the certificate, any redirect from `http://` to `https://` does not happen! May you tell me what is the problem?
Note: All other htaccess conditions and rules are working.

Comment: A downvote for a practical problem which should not be happened normally!

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution to redirect all `http` pages to `https` at the very top of my WordPress `.htaccess` file and in any case before `# BEGIN WordPress` directives.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# # Redirection vers HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#
</IfModule>
```